# How to replace carriage return without new line in FFmpeg output thanks to sed?

Tags: sed, ffmpeg, tr

ffmpeg displays continuously the numbers of frames, the quality of the stream and so on by overwriting previous info after a carriage return.
In Emacs, the result file looks like:

```
frame=11550 fps= 30 q=29.0 size=   50944kB time=00:06:23.23 bitrate=1089.0kbits/s dup=210 drop=7 speed=0.996x    ^Mframe=11565 fps= 30 q=29.0 size=   51200kB time=00:06:23.73 bitrate=1093.0kbits/s dup=210 drop=7 speed=0.996x    ^Mframe=11579 fps= 30 q=29.0 size=   51200kB time=00:06:24.19 bitrate=1091.7kbits/s dup=210 drop=7 speed=0.996x    ^Mframe=11595 fps= 30 q=29.0 size=   51200kB time=00:06:24.73 bitrate=1090.2kbits/s dup=210 drop=7 speed=0.996x    ^Mframe=11610 fps= 30 q=29.0 size=   51456kB time=00:06:25.23 bitrate=1094.2kbits/s dup=210 drop=7 speed=0.996x    ^Mframe=11625 fps= 30 q=29.0 size=   51456kB time=00:06:25.73 bitrate=1092.8kbits/s dup=210 drop=7 speed=0.996x    ^M
```

I tried to remove control characters, replace ^M by newline, replace carriage return by newline too in order to get the frame number and other information later on, but I failed.
Here is my command:

```
stdbuf -o0 tail -f -z ffreport.log| sed -u -e 's/\x1b\[[0-9;]*m//g' -e "s/\r/\n/" -e "s/^M/\n/" -e 's/ \+/\t/g' |stdbuf -o0 grep "frame="|stdbuf -o0 cut -d$'\t' -f2,4,6
```

In fact, the transformation from CR/^M to newline does not seem to work, because when I only keep the first part of sed, I don't get anything.
This command line used to work previously, because my ffmpeg stream had lots of errors, so newlines quite often.
Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: I generally find it easier to replace CR with LF using `tr` as a filter like this `tr '\r' '\n'`

Comment: Thanks Mark. Unfortunately, it doesn't work either.
I fired an hexl editor and got `00000c50: 2020 3078 2020 2020 0d66 7261 6d65 3d20    0x    .frame= ` so it's really a carriage return just before `frame`.

Comment: Ok, take a step back. You are running `ffmpeg` and want to parse its output, which you have redirected to a logfile? Maybe show your `ffmpeg` command and explain what you are looking for and what you want to do when you find it.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are trying to monitor the progress of `ffmpeg` in some way. You may have more success if you get it to write progress in a sensible parsable format to a different file descriptor rather than trying to read stuff intended for the terminal and littered with control codes.

So, you could make a fifo for the progress messages and read them like this:

```
mkfifo ffmpeg.log
cat ffmpeg.log
```

Then run an `ffmpeg` command like this with progress directed to the fifo:

```
fmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=duration=10:size=1920x1080:rate=25 -progress pipe:3 null.mkv 3> ffmpeg.log
```

Comment: That changed quite a lot of things, thank you. I now have one line per information.
`frame=157
fps=42.5
stream_0_0_q=28.0
bitrate=   1.4kbits/s
total_size=724
out_time_ms=4161000
out_time=00:00:04.161000
dup_frames=0
drop_frames=0
speed=1.13x
progress=continue`
I now have to find how to grab the number of frames, the fps, the bitrate and the speed in one command to display it on a oled screen.

Comment: `awk` would be the obvious tool, if you know that? Are you on a Raspberry Pi or some such? How are you driving the OLED?

Comment: I don't know awk yet, but would like to. I am working on an OrangePi [https://www.armbian.com/orange-pi-one/](One) for the time being and will use [https://luma-oled.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python-usage.html#examples](this) OLED library.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot to [Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2836621/mark-setchell) for his answer, on top of which I built my not good (but working) answer.

```
cat ffmpeg.log |awk '/^frame/{split($1,frame,"=")}/^fps/{split($1,fps,"=")}/^speed=.+x$/{split($1,speed,"=");printf "%s|%s|%s\n", frame[2],fps[2],speed[2]}'
```

which gives me what I was looking for, more or less:

```
35|0.0|
47|42.5|
69|42.5|0.394x
91|42.4|0.709x
113|42.6|0.904x
135|42.8|1.04x
157|42.8|1.14x
179|42.8|
201|42.8|1.26x
223|42.8|
245|42.8|1.34x
267|42.8|1.37x
289|42.8|
303|41.7|1.38x
325|41.8|
347|41.9|1.42x
369|41.9|1.44x
391|42.0|1.45x
413|42.0|1.47x
435|42.1|1.48x
457|42.1|1.49x
479|42.2|
501|42.2|1.51x
523|42.3|1.52x
545|42.3|1.53x
559|41.7|1.51x
581|41.8|1.52x
603|41.8|1.52x
```